Blender scale problem with Assets
I have a problem dragging assets into the workspace in various versions of Blender. In the original File the assets itselfs are fine. When I drag them into a new workspace, the actual size is reduced on "0". You can see in the statistics in the screenshot that the object is completely there, but it is reduced to a size of "0". When I change the size, the object is visible again. I can't find any solution in the blender settings or here in the chats.

It doesn't happen with all assets and not always.
